# Mistake in my query, error parsing the query

Tags: c#, sql, .net

There seems to be an error in my query somewhere but for the life of me I cant seem to find it, if anyone could take a look that would be appreciated. Ive tried googling to see if anyone has had the same issue but no luck yet. Sorry if its a duplicate.

```
    public static void InsertMake()
    {

        try
        {
            using (var conn = new SqlCeConnection(_connectionstring))
            {
                if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                {
                    conn.Open();
                }                    
                using (var command = new SqlCeCommand(@"INSERT INTO MAKE(description,lastupdatedone,is_deleted,on_server) VALUES (@Description, @DateTime, @Is_deleted, @On_server", conn))
                {
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Description", Program.Form_mmm.textBoxMake.Text);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateTime", DateTime.Now);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Is_deleted", 0);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@On_server", 0);
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();                      
                    conn.Close();                        
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
        }
```

The error message is

> (0x80004005) There was an error parsing the query. [token line number = 1, token line offset = 114, token in error = @On_server]

Comment: Well what is the error? We can't possibly guess.

Comment: What do you see in messagebox ?

Comment: Why do you think there's an error?  What actual indication of an error are you observing?  (Random guess.... Could it be that you forgot to close the parentheses at the end of the query?)

Comment: This seems to be just a typo, as the closing ")" is missing. Relax and take a break, tiredness can play dirty tricks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're missing the closing parenthesis after VALUES, but you should probably include the error message to be 100% sure that's the problem.

Try changing this line

```
using (var command = new SqlCeCommand(@"INSERT INTO MAKE(description,lastupdatedone,is_deleted,on_server) VALUES (@Description, @DateTime, @Is_deleted, @On_server", conn))
```

to this

```
using (var command = new SqlCeCommand(@"INSERT INTO MAKE(description,lastupdatedone,is_deleted,on_server) VALUES (@Description, @DateTime, @Is_deleted, @On_server)", conn))
```

Comment: Thanks allot mate, my bad to everyone for not adding the error, I rushed a little bit with this question.